# About datagridview control's event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm developed an application for the datagridview filtering . And i used the datagridview's  `dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)`
event for filtering. 
But i want to handle it on the key press event for the datagridview cell. But i'm not getting that type of event.

> the datagridview event should occure
>   on the each keypress..

So can anybody tell me that which event should i use for the datagridview?

please help me...
thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DataGridView.KeyPress` event will **not** be raised when the user types in a particular cell. If you want to be notified each time they press a key while editing content in a cell, you have two options:

1. Handle the `KeyPress` event that is raised directly by the editing control itself (which you can access using the `EditingControlShowing` event).

   For example, you might use the following code:

   ```
   public class Form1 : Form
   {
       public Form1()
       {
           // Add a handler for the EditingControlShowing event
           myDGV.EditingControlShowing += new DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(myDGV_EditingControlShowing);
       }

       private void myDGV_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
       {
           // Ensure that the editing control is a TextBox
           TextBox txt = e.Control as TextBox;
           if (txt != null)
           {
               // Remove an existing event handler, if present, to avoid adding
               // multiple handler when the editing control is reused
               txt.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(txt_KeyPress);

               // Add a handler for the TextBox's KeyPress event
               txt.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(txt_KeyPress);
           }
       }

       private void txt_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
       {
           // Write your validation code here
           // ...

           MessageBox.Show(e.KeyChar.ToString());

       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a custom class that inherits from the standard `DataGridView` control and override its [`ProcessDialogKey` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processdialogkey.aspx). This method is designed to process each key event, even those
   that occur on the editing control. You can either handle the key presses inside of that overridden method, or raise an event of your own to which you can attach a separate handler method.

Comment: but i want rowindex & column index too. then how can i get the rowindex & column index in above code?

Comment: @priyanka: The simplest way is using the [`DataGridView.CurrentCell` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell.aspx). It will return the [cell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.aspx) that is currently selected, which in turn exposes [`ColumnIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.columnindex.aspx) and [`RowIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.rowindex.aspx) properties.

Comment: how to set the e.keychar value to the datagridview current cell?       because when i'm using the above events in my application then that time it shows the current cell as null value & because of which i'm not able to perform the my other operations.

Comment: @priyanka: when you get that cell. You just need to set `e.Handled=false` in Custom KeyPress Event.